# Comparing 2 images using C#

Tags: c#

Can I compare 2 images and show the difference using C#?

How?

Comment: What type of images are they?

Comment: What kind of "difference" do you want to show? Like filesize? Colors? Be a bit more clear to get some nice feedback!

Answer (score 0):

Sure you can.  One (slow) way to do so would be to create a new empty image and then use GetPixel and SetPixel to construct the difference image.

Comment: The FastBitmap class from the DemoFX project can speed things up a little. FastBitmap: http://www.programmersheaven.com/download/51924/34/ZipView.aspx DemoFX: http://www.programmersheaven.com/download/51924/download.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Could be useful perform an image substraction (maybe better in GrayScale mode) as shown here:
[How to subtract one bitmap from another in C#/.NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/397759/how-to-subtract-one-bitmap-from-another-in-c-net)

Answer (score 0):

There is technology called SIFT( Scale Invariant Feature Transform ).This algorithm generates a feature file from an image in which it has salient points of that Image. This file is called SIFT feature.
You have to generate the SIFT feature file for the images that you want to compare. Then this technology has a matching function which you can use to compare the feature files. This function returns a number. the higher the number the more similar the images. in this way you find the most similar images from within a set.